# Go webserver - don't cache files using timestamp

Tags: caching, go, webserver

I'm running a webserver written in go on an embedded system. The timestamp of index.html may go backwards if someone has downgraded the firmware version. If index.html is older than the previous version, the server sends a http 304 response (not modified), and serves a cached version of the file.

The webserver code is using http.FileServer() and http.ListenAndServe().

The problem can easily reproduced by modifying the timestamp of index.html using the Posix command `touch`

```
touch -d"23:59" index.html
```

reloading the page, then

```
touch -d"23:58" index.html
```

reloading this time will give a 304 response on index.html.

Is there a way to prevent timestamp based caching?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming your file server code is like the [example in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix):

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static"))))
```

You can write a handler that sets the appropriate cache headers to prevent this behaviour by stripping ETag headers and setting `Cache-Control: no-cache, private, max-age=0` to prevent caching (both locally and in upstream proxies):

```
var epoch = time.Unix(0, 0).Format(time.RFC1123)

var noCacheHeaders = map[string]string{
    "Expires":         epoch,
    "Cache-Control":   "no-cache, private, max-age=0",
    "Pragma":          "no-cache",
    "X-Accel-Expires": "0",
}

var etagHeaders = []string{
    "ETag",
    "If-Modified-Since",
    "If-Match",
    "If-None-Match",
    "If-Range",
    "If-Unmodified-Since",
}

func NoCache(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Delete any ETag headers that may have been set
        for _, v := range etagHeaders {
            if r.Header.Get(v) != "" {
                r.Header.Del(v)
            }
        }

        // Set our NoCache headers
        for k, v := range noCacheHeaders {
            w.Header().Set(k, v)
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

Use it like so:

```
http.Handle("/static/", NoCache(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static")))))
```

Note: I originally wrote this at [github.com/zenazn/goji/middleware](https://github.com/zenazn/goji/blob/master/web/middleware/nocache.go), so you can also just import that, but it's a simple piece of code to write and I wanted to show a full example for posterity!

Comment: I've already got the no cache headers set in index.html, but it appears that the decision is being made by looking at the file timestamp before checking the headers.

Comment: Your browser/HTTP client can't "see" the timestamp, but yes, `http.FileServer` will set it via `serveContent` [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?#L417) and will set the `Last-Modified` header as per [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?#L282). The other alternative is to call `http.ServeContent` directly inside your own handler and pass `time.Now()` as the `modTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix the problem is to add an etag header to the response. The presence of the etag will make the browser use that, and ignore the last modification date.

More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876760/164802